# Div Transition Effect Not Working

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add Transition on my div "onclick" event):
     http://jsfiddle.net/nKtC6/698/ , (Using jquery)
    and it's doesn't work, so this is what i want with a other example (using CSS) : http://jsfiddle.net/nKtC6/690/

my js seems some problem :

```
$(function() {                       
  $("#icon").click(function() {
    $("animate1").removeClass("animate1-nomove").addClass("animate1-move");      
    $("animate2").removeClass("animate2-nomove").addClass("animate2-move");  
  });
});
```

and css

```
.animate1-nomove {left: -100px;}
.animate2-nomove {left: 0px;}

.animate1-move {left: 0px;}
.animate2-move {left: 150px; background-color: red;}
```

it's not possible to add this effect with js ? i doesn't like jquery animate (for example) , i prefer css3 solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the class selector in your `$("animate1")` and `$("animate2")`, should be `$(".animate1")` and `$(".animate2")`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your `selectors` inside `#icon.click callback`, you missed the dots for the classes:

```
    $("animate1").removeClass("animate1-nomove").addClass("animate1-move");      
    $("animate2").removeClass("animate2-nomove").addClass("animate2-move");  
    // should be
    $(".animate1").removeClass("animate1-nomove").addClass("animate1-move");      
    $(".animate2").removeClass("animate2-nomove").addClass("animate2-move");
```

That said, here's a working example with the `click` event instead of `hover`:
http://jsfiddle.net/ffNw6/